# Copy files by extension in VS Code tasks.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want to copy, recursively, all files from /src with the extension .json to my /out directory. I currently copy all files in my static folder (regardless of extension) like this, in tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "copyStatic",
            "command" : "cp",
            "args": ["-f", "-r", "${workspaceFolder}/src/static", "${workspaceFolder}/out/"],
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried using the /**/ notation I'd seen elsewhere like this

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "copyJson",
            "command" : "cp",
            "args": ["-f", "-r", "${workspaceFolder}/src/**/*.json", "${workspaceFolder}/out/"],
        }
    ]
}
```

But it didn't work - got an error `cp: /src/**/*.json: No such file or directory`

Any ideas how to do this in tasks.json? I want to deep copy so include files like

```
/src/foo.json --> /out/foo.json
/src/folder/bar.json --> /out/folder/bar.json
```

Thanks

Comment: `"command" : "find ./async -name '*.json' -exec cp --parents {} out/ ';'",` comes darn close (where `async` is your target directory name) - it'll put the target directory name in the output folder too though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `gulp` solution is quite easy:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");

function copyJSONFiles() {

  return gulp.src('src/**/*.json')   // get all the json files from 'src' directory
    .pipe(gulp.dest('out'));        // move them to the workspace/out directory
}

exports.default = copyJSONFiles;


// /src/foo.json --> /out/foo.json
// /src/folder/bar.json --> /out/folder/bar.json
```

This file, called `gulpfile.js`, goes into your workspace folder at the top level.  It is triggered with just the `gulp` command in the terminal.

The `out` folder will be created and the folder structure under `src` will be preserved within it.

---

As I said in my comment on October 13

`"command" : "find ./async -name '*.json' -exec cp --parents {} out/ ';'",`

will preserve the folder structure of the src directory (here `async`) but unfortunately under `out/async`.  That is the purpose of the `--parents` option.

However, not using the `--parents` options results in just a flat folder of json files which it doesn't seem you want.

There is probably a pure script version that will flatten that parent folder removing the `src` folder therein.  But the gulp version is awfully easy.

Answer (score 1):

Complex queries can be quite hard to achieve with `cp`. Fortunately,`find` searches recursively by default, and can be used in combination with an `-exec cp` to actually copy these files.

The following command does the trick:

```
"command" : "find src/ -name "*.json" -exec cp {} out/ \;"
```

Comment: This does not maintain the folder structure under `src` as the OP desires: see `/out/folder/bar.json`